# Is there a group $(S, \times, n)$, such that $n^{-1} \neq n?$

Tags: group-theory

> Is there a group $( S, \times, n)$, such that $n^{-1} \neq n?$

I think it is not possible since;

$$\begin{align}
m \times n = n \times m &\implies n^{-1} \times n 
= n \times n^{-1}\\
& \implies n^{-1} \times (n \times b) = (n \times n^{-1}) \times b \\
& \implies n^{-1} \times b= n \times b\\
&\implies n = n^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

EDIT: There have been tremendous downvotes to close this question, so I will clarify what I mean, in the hope it can be figured out what I mean.

**In my mind** - and I think this is proper notation -

$\langle S, \times, n\rangle$ is the notation of a Group, where S is the set of the Group, $\times$ is the operation to be performed and $n$ is the neutral element. So what my question asks, if the inverse of the neutral element cannot be the neutral element itself...

EDIT EDIT: I edited the notation

Comment: Can you explain the third arrow?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that, on any group, the inverse of any element is always another (distinct) element of the group?

Comment: nah, contrary... I made a typo and trying to fix it...

Comment: Sure there are: $S_3$, or $C_4$. In fact, nearly all groups have at least one element $g$ such that $g \neq g^{-1}$. Better would be to try to identify exactly which groups have the property that $g=g^{-1}$ for all elements $g$. These are just the elementary abelian $2$-groups.

Comment: So why my proof is wrong?

Comment: @eduard Is there still a need for an explanation after edit?

Comment: The third arrow is wrong. Somehow $n xb$ becomes $b$ and $n^{-1} xb$ also becomes $b$. Here you are assuming that $n=n^{-1}$... Your proof basically shows that if $n=n^{-1}=e$ then $n=n^{-1}$.

Comment: Is $n$ the identity of your group? If yes, then it is always true that $e=e^{-1}$ and your proof is much longer than it needs.

Comment: Yes, n ist the identity of my group as stated in the question. Can you show me a faster proof?

Comment: It's not stated in your question that $n$ is the identity of your group. It's also not stated what $m$ or $b$ are supposed to be. It's not stated why $n$ and $m$ commute. A lot of things are not stated in your question.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi 

$<S, \times, n>$ What is the n for then?

Comment: I can't read your mind, how would I know?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704289/does-the-identity-element-of-a-group-have-an-inverse/1704292

Comment: It is not often I vote to close a question for lack of clarity, but I just voted that way on this one. I don't think even its author understands what it is supposed to be about.

Comment: @almagest So may I explain, what it is about?

Comment: @TVSuchty Sure, go ahead.

Comment: @almagest I have edited to explain the intent of the question...

Comment: The mistake you have made was to use weird notation and to assume that those who read your question will understand what you mean. Nobody writes groups like you do. If you need to specify the underlying set, the multiplication rule and the neutral element you should write instead $(G,\cdot, 1_G)$ or $(G,\cdot, e)$. or whatever your preferred symbol for multiplication in a group is.

Comment: It is interesting since my Computer Science teacher - who studied mathematics taught me this notation. I link it here:

https://www7.in.tum.de/um/courses/ds/ws1920/files/slides/_slides_5_algebra-handout.pdf

Site: 10

Unfortunately, there is no English version available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very easy proof. By definition of inverse, $n\times n^{-1} = n$. But by definition of identity $n \times n^{-1} = n^{-1}$. So $n = n^{-1}$.